# How to correctly define a new style in the biocon package so that its behavior matches the default behavior? Extra: Reset in each chapter

Tags: macros, packages

I am using the `biocon` package to deal with the scientific names of species in my thesis. Sometimes the names need to be accompanied by the strain of each species, so I decided to use the `\newtaxon` and `\newtaxastyle` commands as indicated in the package manual (https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/biocon/manual.pdf).

The default output is to show the full species name the first time it is called, and subsequent times it appears in abbreviated form.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biocon}

\begin{document}

\newbact{rr}{genus=Raphidiopsis, epithet=raciborskii}

Common behaviour:\\
\bact{rr} and \bact{rr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I use the new style, the behavior is not the same as the default.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biocon}

\begin{document}

\newtaxon{strain}
\newtaxastyle{strain}{\taxit{\taxonfirst{!genus!.}\taxon{~!epithet!}}\taxon{~!strain!}}
\newbact{rr}{genus=Raphidiopsis, epithet=raciborskii, strain=CYP011K}

Undesired behaviour:\\
\bact[strain]{rr} and \bact[strain]{rr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Extra if it is possible:** Is there any way to reset for each chapter? i.e. to show in each chapter the full name of the species when it first appears .

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Every time you  use `bact[f]{rr}` after the first use you get (only) the full name. Whith `\bactF[f]{rr}` you get the full name + the strain.

[image: e]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biocon}

\newcommand{\bactF}[2][]{% new <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \bact[#1]{#2}\bact[strainx]{#2}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \newtaxon{strain}
    \newtaxastyle{strain}{\taxit{\taxonfirst{!genus!.}\taxon{~!epithet!}}\taxon{~!strain!}}
    \newbact{rr}{genus=Raphidiopsis, epithet=raciborskii, strain=CYP011K}
    \newtaxastyle{strainx}{\taxon{~!strain!}} % new <<<<<<<<<<<<
            
    Common like  behaviour:
    
    \bact{rr} (first use) 
    
    \bactF[f]{rr} (full name with strain)
    
    \bact[strain]{rr} (abbrev name with strain)
    
    \bact{rr} (second use)
    
    \bact[f]{rr} (only full name)
    
    \bigskip
    
    \bactF[f]{rr} and   \bact[strain]{rr} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I use "`\bact[strain]{rr}`  and `\bact[strain]{rr}`", I get "R. raciborskii CYP011K and R. raciborskii CYP011K" instead of "Raphidioipsis raciborskii CYP011K and R. raciborskii CYP011K".

Comment: @Daniel Valencia C. Please try the updated answer.